# Is this Gameloop causing a Memory Leak?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I have created my Game Loop like so:

```
var lastTime = 0;
var nextTime = 0;
function prepareUpdate(callback) {
    currentTime = Date.now();
    nextTime = mathMax(lastTime + (1000 / targetFPS), currentTime);
    return setTimeout(function prepUpdate() {
        callback(lastTime = nextTime);
    }, nextTime - currentTime);
};

function callUpdate() {
    prepareUpdate(callUpdate);
    updateGameLoop();
};
callUpdate();
```

I am doing it this way because I have run into some issues with RequestAnimationFrame. But Now I am experiencing some lag due to the Garbage Collector kicking in every 5 seconds. I am wondering if the update code is causing this, because I am returning the setTimeout function the way I am.

Is there a way to rewrite this to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Take several heap snapshots using chrome dev tools and see what *exactly* is garbage-collected.

Comment: Btw, it's not obvious why you return something from `prepareUpdate` and then not use the returned result.

Comment: *"I am wondering if the update code is causing this, because I am returning the setTimeout function the way I am"* - do you mean the `return setTimeout()... `? I don't see how that could be the problem: that just returns an id that you ignore. Seems more likely that something in `updateGameLoop()` is causing the problem - do you notice any garbage collection issues if you comment out that call and just run an "empty" loop?

Comment: I have completely commented out the updateGameLoop now. But the GC still exists. This is really odd. could be some extensions that I am running perhaps.